LWC: Upload file changes the Date format automatically. How to convert back to another format?
I have an .xls file with the date column in the format DD/MM/YYYY like this:

However, when I uploaded file by <lightning-input type="file [...]></lightning-input> tag, the format of dates are changed to Integer number like this:

How to convert them back to the original format? Thanks

This question is similar to: Catch and change locale Excel date format when importing to ISO8601. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
